# Aircraft Travel: Valid IDs

Tags: airport-security

In the US, a valid ID is required at security checkpoints.  Some US drivers licenses do not meet requirements.  Fortunately, mine does.

That being said, when boarding a plane outside the US a passport is 'gold' standard.  However, when outside the US, are there other generally accepted forms of ID such as a US driver's license or a US passport card?

Comment: This is specifically outside of US, if I read the question right.

Comment: @chx thanks, I misread. In that case I should have voted to close as too broad, but I can't change my vote now.

Comment: Requirements vary widely, but in general, for most domestic flights foreign travelers can only use passports or domestic IDs (which they'll only have if they reside in the country).

Comment: "Some US drivers licenses do not meet requirements." *All* states' regular driver's licenses are valid for domestic air travel until at least January 22, 2018 regardless of meeting any requirements. Unless you are talking about special types of driver's licenses issued by some states that don't require legal presence documents.

Comment: "Generally" the answer is no.  When outside your home country, your passport IS your only official ID.  There are exceptions such as EU citizens traveling in different EU member nations, but for most of the citizens of the world, your passport is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. If we are talking of international travel, then we have at least https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refugee_travel_document https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Convention_travel_document https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_laissez-passer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_laissez-passer

But the question is extremely broad if we also allow for domestic travel. There are more than a few countries where domestic flights exist and collecting the acceptable documents for each is a very big task.